# Unmarshalling indented XML gives different result in Java 7 vs 8

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Switching to Java 8 made one of my tests fail. Here is a condensed example:

```
public static class Wrapper {
    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    public List<Object> content;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, JAXBException {
    final String xml = "<a>\n  <b/>\n</a>";
    final XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    final XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(xml));

    final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Wrapper.class);
    final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    final JAXBElement<Wrapper> element = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Wrapper.class);

    System.out.println(element.getValue().content);
}
```

Output with Java 7 (1.7.0_75): `ElementNSImpl`, `String`

```
[[b: null], 
]
```

Output Java 8 (1.8.0_45): `String`, `ElementNSImpl`, `String`

```
[
  , [b: null], 
]
```

Java 7 seems to ignore leading whitespace in this case, while Java 8 does not. My questions are:

- What is the root cause for this different behavior?
- How to make Java 8 behave as Java 7? Or at least have consistent behavior with both Java versions?

PS: `@XmlMixed @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)` sounds horrible, but the code of the "wrapper" class was generated from a SharePoint WSDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the default StAX parser bundled with the Java runtime (which may behave differently in different versions), you should pick a specific version of a specific parser and have your application depend on that.  You could simply include the JARs for (e.g.) [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org) on your application's classpath, and rely on the default behaviour of `XMLInputFactory.newFactory()` to prefer that over the bundled one, but safer (and more performant) would be to instantiate the appropriate object directly yourself.

```
XMLInputFactory xif = new com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory();
```

That way you're absolutely guaranteed to be using the parser you think you are, regardless of what other JAR files get added to the classpath/class loader by any other libraries.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Can two parsers safely co-exist in the same application? I am considering to use a specific implementation here and leave other code for XML parsing with the default one.

Comment: @stholzm two parsers can safely coexist, though once Woodstox is on the classpath it will typically be used by `XMLInputFactory.newFactory()` in preference to the one that is built into rt.jar. The issue is if some other library pulls in another parser (sjsxp) then you can't be sure which one will win. Using `new WstxInputFactory()` removes the reflective lookup so you know what you're getting.